# Can probability increase on failed dice rolls?

Tags: probability

If I have a 20 sided die and I want to roll a 20, and I have failed 100 times, can the probability increase because of the failed attempts? I am pretty sure this is a no, but had to ask!

Comment: No, the probability could only decrease, as failing $100$ times in a row increases the chances that the die is loaded against $20$.

Comment: It's not so bad with a $20$-sided die, but if I threw a six-sided die $100$ times, and I never got a $6$, I would start to suspect it was loaded, which _will_ affect the probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each subsequent roll would be the exact same 1/20 chance of getting any value, on its own.  When quantified and taken as a group however you should expect a 20 approximately 5 times in a 100 rolls, and to that extent, a batch of rolls would have a higher chance of rolling a value that hasn't been rolled yet.

The final chart should, given a large enough sample of attempted rolls, provide an even spread of all values.

Comment: You should NOT expect to see $20$ $5$ times out of $100$. It will be $Bin(100,1/20)\approx Pois(5)$ and hence probability to see exactly five $20$'s is $\approx 18\%$ only